# Computation Tree Logic - boolean combinations of path formuas

Tags: logic, computer-science

So apparently the syntax of CTL does not allow boolean combinations of path formulas. I'm not even sure I fully understand this sentence. I think it states something like "in CTL, we cannot express a logic statement using the universal or existential quantifier such that the statement holds for every path in a model".

My question is: How can I rewrite a formula which is valid in CTL* in terms of CTL? E.g.: $ A[Fp \rightarrow Xq]$

This expression says: "For all paths in my model, if there is a future state p, then the next state will be q."

In CTL, I would write this as: $EFp \rightarrow AXq$

This translates to "If there is some future state p, then for all states in which p is true, the next states will be q."

Comment: anyone? I'd be happy to read it up, but haven't found any good literature so far

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, in CTL every quantifier **must** be followed by a path formula and every path formula operation **must** be quantified.

Your second expression is vaild in CTL as $E$ quantifies $F$ and $A$ quantifies $X$.

However, they are not the same. In the CTL* formula only paths that eventually lead to $p$ are required to have have $q$ at the next state, while in the CTL formula you say if $p$ is reachable, all possible following states must be $q$.

You can rephrase the CTL* statement (paths that eventually lead to $p$ are required to have have $q$ at the next state) with negation like this: "For all following states, if the next state is NOT $q$, then from that state on we must never reach $p$. Or as CTL:

$AX(\neg q \rightarrow AG(\neg p))$